# How to set default value for DateTime field in NavigationMixin?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

```
    const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({ 
        StartDateTime: '2022-08-22 20:00:00',
    });
    
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate({
    
    type: 'standard_objectPage",
    
    attributes: {    
        objectApiName: 'Event", 
        actionName: 'new'
    },
    
    state : {    
       navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST', 
       defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
    }

 });
```

I am building a Lightning Web Component in which I am try to make a functionality, on a click of button it navigate to new record page of Event object. Here I am trying to provide default value to StartDateTime field of Event Object but it isn't accepting this value.

Comment: For future reference, please read [Why should I not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8682068). Once copy-pasted the code you could format it clicking `{}` or you could read [how to enable syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datetime string must be in ISO format with `T` between date and time with the time offest of UTC: `Z`.
This means that if you want to see `20:00:00` in UI, so **in your time zone**, unless you're in GMT+0 you should add or subtract your time zone.

I'm at GMT+2 so I have to subtract 2 hours:

```js
const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
    StartDateTime: '2022-08-22T18:00:00Z'
});
```

Anyway it's better option creating a Date object and call [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), which returns always zero UTC offset datetime string, handling the time zone for you:

```js
const startDate = new Date('2022-08-22T20:00:00'); // please note the T
const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
    StartDateTime: startDate.toISOString()
});
```

Date object has also a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) that takes `(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds)`, so you can build it this way:

```js
const startDate = new Date(2022, 7, 22, 20, 0, 0);
```

Please note that the value for August is `7`, since it's a zero-based index so zero indicates the first month of the year